# Error Android RecyclerView Adapter Skipped x frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola tengo en un activity un recyclerView y en el adapter estoy haciendo algunas validaciones con TextWatcher cuando scroleo hacia abajo y hacia arriba varias veces me sale el siguiente error va en aumento los frames Skipped 57 frames!... Skipped 306 frames!... Skipped 4230 frames! hasta que se cierra la aplicación. Las validaciones que estoy haciendo con el TextWatcher son las siguientes:

1. Que solo se pueda escribir un "-".
2. Que solo se pueda escribir un ".".
3. Que el caracter "-" solo se pueda escribir en la posicion 0 del EditText.

Este es mi TextWatcher en el metodo **setPalletTemp** ejecutado en el método **onBindViewHolder** de la clase **OrdenAdapter.java**

```
tvTemperatura.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    //beforeTextChanged = s.toString();
                    //Log.i("beforeTextChanged", "---------------------------");
                    //Log.i("beforeTextChanged", "CharSequence: " + s.toString());
                    //Log.i("beforeTextChanged", "start: " + start);
                    //Log.i("beforeTextChanged", "count: " + count);
                    //Log.i("beforeTextChanged", "after: " + after);
                    //Log.i("beforeTextChanged", "---------------------------");
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    //Log.i("onTextChanged", "beforeTextChanged: " + beforeTextChanged);
                    //Log.i("onTextChanged", "CharSequence: " + s.toString());
                    //Log.i("onTextChanged", "start: " + start);
                    //Log.i("onTextChanged", "before: " + before);
                    //Log.i("onTextChanged", "count: " + count);
                    //Log.i("onTextChanged", "---------------------------");
                    posicionesGuiones = contarCaracteres(s.toString(), '-');
                    posicionesPuntos = contarCaracteres(s.toString(), '.');
                    comienzo = start;
                    despues = before;


                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    //Log.i("afterTextChanged", "Editable: " + s.toString());
                    //Log.i("afterTextChanged", "Comienzo + 1: " + (comienzo + 1));
                    //Log.i("afterTextChanged", "tvTemperatura.getText().toString() " + tvTemperatura.getText().toString());
                    //Log.i("afterTextChanged", "tvTemperatura.getText().length() " + tvTemperatura.getText().length());
                    //StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s.toString());
                    int guiones = posicionesGuiones.size();
                    int puntos = posicionesPuntos.size();
                    //Log.i("afterTextChanged", "posiciones: " + gson.toJson(posicionesGuiones) + " tamaño: " + guiones);
                    //Log.i("afterTextChanged", "comienzo: "+comienzo);
                    //Log.i("afterTextChanged", "before: " + despues);
                    String text = s.toString();


                    if(guiones > 1){
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s.toString());
                        //Log.i("afterTextChanged", "stringBuilder.toString() antes: " + stringBuilder.toString());
                        stringBuilder = stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(posicionesGuiones.get(posicionesGuiones.size() - 1));
                        text = stringBuilder.toString();
                        //Log.i("afterTextChanged", "stringBuilder.toString() despues: " +stringBuilder.toString());
                        if(despues == 0){
                            comienzo--;
                        }else{
                            comienzo++;
                        }
                    }else if(guiones == 1){
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s.toString());
                        if (posicionesGuiones.get(0) != 0) {
                            //Log.i("afterTextChanged", "stringBuilder.toString() antes: " + stringBuilder.toString());
                            stringBuilder = stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(posicionesGuiones.get(0));
                            text = stringBuilder.toString();
                            //Log.i("afterTextChanged", "stringBuilder.toString() despues: " +stringBuilder.toString());
                            if(despues == 0){
                                comienzo--;
                            }else{
                                comienzo++;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(puntos > 1){
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s.toString());
                        //Log.i("afterTextChanged", "stringBuilder.toString() antes: " + stringBuilder.toString());
                        stringBuilder = stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(posicionesPuntos.get(posicionesPuntos.size() - 1));
                        text = stringBuilder.toString();
                        //Log.i("afterTextChanged", "stringBuilder.toString() despues: " +stringBuilder.toString());
                        if(despues == 0){
                            comienzo--;
                        }else{
                            comienzo++;
                        }
                    }


                    tvTemperatura.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    tvTemperatura.setText(text);
                    tvTemperatura.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    palletTempModelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).temperatura = text;
                    if(comienzo == 5 && despues == 0){
                        tvTemperatura.setSelection(tvTemperatura.getText().length());
                    }else if(comienzo < 5 && despues == 0){
                        tvTemperatura.setSelection(comienzo + 1);
                    }else if(comienzo >= 1 && despues == 1){
                        tvTemperatura.setSelection(comienzo);
                    }
                    //Log.i("afterTextChanged", "------------------------------------");
                }
            });
```

Funciona pero me sale el error I/Choreographer: Skipped 4230 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread cuando scroleo varias veces.

Les dejo un gif del error en un lado esta el dispositivo android que se ejecuta y en toda la pantalla esta el logcat del Android Studio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo acá el error:

```
2021-05-02 22:43:04.372 4234-4294/com.luismiguel.recyclerviewet I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1140ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=303742509961228, Vsync=303742676627888, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=303742688071561, AnimationStart=303742688124478, PerformTraversalsStart=303743639566604, DrawStart=303743641116552, SyncQueued=303743647110199, SyncStart=303743647616084, IssueDrawCommandsStart=303743648020251, SwapBuffers=303743650403897, FrameCompleted=303743651393272, DequeueBufferDuration=219000, QueueBufferDuration=515000, 
2021-05-02 22:43:04.376 4234-4234/com.luismiguel.recyclerviewet I/Choreographer: Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-05-02 22:43:11.569 4234-4234/com.luismiguel.recyclerviewet I/Choreographer: Skipped 306 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-05-02 22:43:12.338 4234-4294/com.luismiguel.recyclerviewet I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=5882ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=303745733746895, Vsync=303750833746691, OldestInputEvent=303746375000000, NewestInputEvent=303749718000000, HandleInputStart=303750848482166, AnimationStart=303751605372189, PerformTraversalsStart=303751605410627, DrawStart=303751606841565, SyncQueued=303751612524794, SyncStart=303751613112815, IssueDrawCommandsStart=303751613502034, SwapBuffers=303751616011670, FrameCompleted=303751616905055, DequeueBufferDuration=227000, QueueBufferDuration=328000, 
2021-05-02 22:43:19.127 4234-4294/com.luismiguel.recyclerviewet I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=5019ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=303753386340119, Vsync=303753436340117, OldestInputEvent=303753374000000, NewestInputEvent=303753462000000, HandleInputStart=303753452534196, AnimationStart=303758390072657, PerformTraversalsStart=303758390233959, DrawStart=303758391494532, SyncQueued=303758396906303, SyncStart=303758397469741, IssueDrawCommandsStart=303758397916095, SwapBuffers=303758401070314, FrameCompleted=303758405920315, DequeueBufferDuration=335000, QueueBufferDuration=2237000, 
2021-05-02 22:43:25.456 4234-4251/com.luismiguel.recyclerviewet I/.recyclerviewe: Thread[7,tid=4251,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x7492af4400,peer=0x138802b0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2021-05-02 22:43:25.591 4234-4251/com.luismiguel.recyclerviewet I/.recyclerviewe: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
2021-05-02 22:44:24.690 4234-4234/com.luismiguel.recyclerviewet I/Choreographer: Skipped 4230 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-05-02 22:44:24.743 4234-4294/com.luismiguel.recyclerviewet I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=70567ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=303753453212959, Vsync=303823953210139, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=303823969016534, AnimationStart=303823969043877, PerformTraversalsStart=303823969079919, DrawStart=303824011674767, SyncQueued=303824017320757, SyncStart=303824017993726, IssueDrawCommandsStart=303824018410757, SwapBuffers=303824020878153, FrameCompleted=303824021763414, DequeueBufferDuration=262000, QueueBufferDuration=377000,
```

Si me pueden ayudar con este error es dentro del adapter **OrdenTempAdapter.java** donde hago las validaciones.

Les dejo el código aquí: https://github.com/Miguel546/recyclerviewET.git

Answer (score -1):

Para las validaciones que estás solicitando, el mismo EditText lo puede hacer sin necesidad de usar un TextWatcher.
Prueba quitando o comentando tu TextWatcher, y en el XML de tu EditText, debes quitar esta línea:
android:digits="0123456789.-"

Comment: Quitando la linea **android:digits="0123456789.-"** hace que el usuario pueda ingresar otros caracteres que yo no quiero. Por otro lado el EditText como haría las validaciones sin el TextWatcher?

Comment: Si ejecutas el código del git en Android Studio veras que las validaciones funcionan bien con el textwatcher.

Comment: He visto que usas android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal", por lo que permite ver solo el teclado numérico y se puede añadir solo números decimales, con punto decimal y signo. En todo caso, ¿que caracteres de más te está permitiendo ingresar?

Comment: La "," y otro caracterer que aparece en el teclado numerico del android. Pero como se haría que el no pueda ingresar mas de dos puntos y mas de dos menos y que el menos solo pueda ingresarse en el primer caracter?

Comment: Podrías intentar agregar lo siguiente:
tvTemperatura.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,true));

en vez de tu TextWatcher

Comment: Es que hay un problema el textwatcher me sirve porque al final voy a comparar la lista que se ingresa actualmente con la que salió al inicio y en el textwatcher hay una línea  palletTempModelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).temperatura = text; que sirve para comparar por lo que necesito el textwatcher.

Comment: Creo que la solución esta en poner tvTemperatura.removeTextChangedListener(this); y tvTemperatura.addTextChangedListener(this); en los 3 métodos beforeTextChanged, onTextChanged y afterTextChanged en el lugar correcto.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que usas el "setText" dentro de algunos de esos 3 métodos, eso se debe evitar ya que genera un bucle infinito. Podrías tal vez usar un InputFilter para hacer tu validación, pero en tu método afterTextChange solo deberías tener esto:  palletTempModelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).temperatura = s.toString();

Comment: He quitado todos los "setText" y he puesto log despues de ese text watcher y no me pinta sabes porque? }else if(comienzo >= 1 && despues == 1){
                        //tvTemperatura.setSelection(comienzo);
                        posicion = comienzo;
                    }
                }
            });

            Log.i("hola", "hola");
            Log.i("isEmpty", text + " " + !text.isEmpty());

Comment: Mira la rama nopintatvtemperatura https://github.com/Miguel546/recyclerviewET/blob/nopintatvtemperatura/app/src/main/java/com/luismiguel/recyclerviewet/OrdenTempAdapter.java de la linea 169 a la 174 no funciona sabes porque?